# check which columns in list have exact string value and extract the column and row

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame (
  A = c("ABC11234","ABC11"),
  B = c(11,1),
  C = c("11",11),
  D =  c(11.1,"11.1"))
```

and I apply this function to tell me which rows and columns have this exact string and assign the output to 'a'

```
a<- lapply(df, function(x) grep("^11$",x))
```

Now I get a list and I want to:

1. extract the pairs (column [name], and row [value]) so that I can know exactly which column, row has the exact string I'm looking for in the lapply.

In the above DF example with grep, I want to know that B = 1 and C = 1,2 (e.g. column B/row 1 and column C/row 1 and row 2 have a value of "^11$")

I've tried to do something like a == integer(0) or unlist(a) but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you want things like below

```
a <- transform(
  as.data.frame(
    which(matrix(grepl("^11$", as.matrix(df)), nrow = nrow(df)),
    arr.ind = TRUE
  )),
  col = names(df)[col]
)
```

which gives

```
> a
  row col
1   1   B
2   1   C
3   2   C
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the output you want is just the column names and the row numbers within those columns that contain your desired "string." It's not clear if you want to avoid having the numeric `11`'s included as well because the string functions will coerce the numbers into strings. However here's my solution for which I used the `stringr` package instead of base. I start by extracting all of the elements that fulfill your regex (i.e. the whole "string" is `"11"`)

```
    library(stringr)
    d <- lapply(df, function(x) str_extract_all(x,"^11$"))
```

This produces a list with length equal to the number of columns to the data frame. Each element of the list has the same number  of elements as rows in the column and is either `"11"` or `character(0)`. Now we take the indices of all the elements of the list that meet the condition of having length greater than 0 (i.e. your desired string appears in the column at least once).

```
    lapply(d, function (x) which(x>0))
```

This produces another list of length 4. Each element is a vector containing the row #'s for each column which met your condition.

Let's unlist this

```
    e <- unlist(lapply(d, function (x) which(x>0)))
```

This produces a named vector where the item in the vector is the row number and the name is the column:

```
    B C1 C2 
    2  1  2
```

To get rid of the duplicate column names (C1, C2, etc) we'll do one more string function to replace any column name followed by a letter with just the column name:

```
    names(e) <- str_replace_all(names(e),"([A-Z])\\d","\\1")
```

The output for `e` is:

```
    B C C 
    1 1 2
```

All the code together:

```
    library(stringr)
    d <- lapply(df, function(x) str_extract_all(x,"^11$"))
    lapply(d, function (x) which(x>0))
    e<- unlist(lapply(d, function (x) which(x>0)))
    names(e) <- str_replace_all(names(e),"([A-Z])\\d","\\1")
    e
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `lapply()`:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame (
  A = c("ABC11234","ABC11"),
  B = c(11,1),
  C = c("11",11),
  D =  c(11.1,"11.1"),stringsAsFactors = F)
#List
a<- lapply(df, function(x) grep("^11$",x))
#List 2
a[lapply(a,length)==0]
```

Output:

```
$A
integer(0)

$D
integer(0)
```

And if you want to extract that values from your `df` you could do this:

```
df[,rownames(do.call(rbind,a[lapply(a,length)==0]))]
```

Output:

```
         A    D
1 ABC11234 11.1
2    ABC11 11.1
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is also to reshape to 'long' format and then get the corresponding column names

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), as.character), row = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -row, names_to = 'col') %>%
    group_by(row) %>% 
    summarise(col = unique(col[str_detect(value, '^11$')]), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    row col  
#  <int> <chr>
#1     1 B    
#2     1 C    
#3     2 C
```